# How to add two columns of SparseVectors using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sparse-matrix

Given two DataFrame columns of SparseVector objects, how can you add (i.e. vector addition) the two columns together to create new column?

Something like

```
df.columns
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [v1: SparseVector, v2: SparseVector]

df.withColumn("v3", ADD_COL_FUNCTION(col(v1), col(v2)))
```

Comment: Please define "add". Concatenate? Elementwise addition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is our final solution to this problem.

First, we implemented the implicit conversions between Spark and Breeze vectors provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32458913/5061485) (note the bug fixes in comments). This provides the `asBreeze` and `fromBreeze` conversions used in the code below.

Then we defined a function that allows addition of columns of sparse vectors:

```
def addVectors(v1Col: String, v2Col: String, outputCol: String)
            : DataFrame => DataFrame = {
  df: DataFrame => {
    def add(v1: SparkVector, v2: SparkVector): SparkVector =
      (v1.asBreeze + v2.asBreeze).fromBreeze
    val func = udf((v1: SparkVector, v2: SparkVector) => add(v1, v2))
    df.withColumn(outputCol, func(col(v1Col), col(v2Col)))
  }
}
```

This function is called using:

```
 df.transform(addVectors(col1Name, col2name, colOutName))
```

You may, of course, want to include some checks for presence of column names, and to make sure the output column doesn't over-write anything you don't want it to.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in addition function for SparseVectors in Spark. `DenseVector` objects can be dealt with by turning them into arrays, but for a `SparseVector` this could be a memory killer. You can interpret SparseVectors as a map, then 'add' the maps together.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{SparseVector, Vectors, Vector}

def addVecCols(v1: SparseVector, v2: SparseVector): Vector = {
  val map1: Map[Int, Double] = (v1.indices zip v1.values).toMap

  Vectors.sparse(v1. size, 
    (map1 ++ (v2.indices zip v2.values).toMap)
      .map{ case (k, v) => k -> (v + map1.getOrElse(k, 0d))}
      .toList
  )


val addVecUDF = udf((v1: SparseVector, v2: SparseVector) => addVecCols(v1, v2))
```

Note that in Spark 1.6, the return type of `Vectors.sparse` is `Vector`, while in Spark 2.X, it is `SparseVector`, so adjust the return type of `addVecCols` appropriately. Also, in 2.X, you can use the `ml` library instead of the `mllib` library.

Using this on a dataframe would be

```
val outDF = inDF.withColumn("added", addVecUDF(col("one_vector"), col("other_vector")))
```